# Mac: sandbox creation failed: 1002 (operation couldn't be completed 13)

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, entitlements

Trying to migrate an app to sandbox and receiving this error on first launch.  Subsequent launches are successful but nothing is migrated from prior data file locations.

```
xpchelper reply message validation: sandbox creation failed: 1002
Container object initialization failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 13.)
```

Have tried repairing permissions but no luck so far.

Any info would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same bug referenced in other places whereby symlinks in any user directory cause container creation to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after doing the following things:
 - Upgraded to 10.9
 - Changes the affected account from standard user to
   admin.

After reviewing the access rights to user's folder, the read flag for user was not set. I can't imaging that I remove it. But set the read flag solved the issue.